# Failing to Show Custom Sentinel 2 Image Collection on a Map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, sentinel-2

I'm creating a custom image collection over a bound region as follows:

1. Get image collection containing images taken by satellite in 7 days

```
var collection_to_covert_to_image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2").filterDates(d1, d2).filterBounds(roi);
```

2. Convert image collection to a single image:

```
var img = collection_to_convert_to_image.toBands();
```

> Now this creates an image with bands list as a sum of all images in
> collection. Like instead of correct B1, B2, B3, B4, etc it is creating
> bands list having *IMAGE_1_DATE_B1, ...IMAGE_1_DATE_B2, ...,
> IMAGE_2_DATE_B1, IMAGE_2_DATE_B2, ...*
>
> What I want the resulting combined image from image collection to have
> B1, B2, B3, B4, ...

3. Repeat Steps 1 and 2 to get multiple 'combined' images and then creating image collection as follows:

```
var custom_col = ee.ImageCollection([ combined_img_1, combined_img_2, ... ]);
```

Finally to preview this collection, I add first image to the map:

```
Map.addLayer(custom_col.first(), { min: 0, max: 6000 });
```

But nothing gets displayed although layer is loaded. I believe this is because of new images not having proper B1, B2, etc bands

So how to make combined image that contains these bands as sum of child images' respective bands like e.g *combined_img_B1 = img1_B1 + img2_B1 + ...* in order to display it on map?

Answer (score 1):

> how to make combined image that contains these bands as sum of child images' respective bands

```
var img = collection_to_convert_to_image.sum();
```

You can also use `.median()`, `.mean()` and other such common mathematical operations.

The general tool is `imageCollection.reduce(reducer)` and then you can use any EE reducer to combine the images into one image; `.sum()` is a shortcut for `.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())` and so on.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Kevin, it worked using `.sum()` But here's a small issue arising: It does create and show new combined image. But this image is showing edges of child images. They are not seen when showing initial image collection of children images on a map. Why is it so?

Comment: @Wallee When do `Map.addLayer` on an image collection, the default behavior is to _mosaic_ the collection: at each pixel, to take the _most recent_ image. That is available as the `.mosaic()` operation on collections. But if you take the _sum_, then the magnitude of the value will depend on the _number of images being summed_ at each point. Thus, overlaps are brighter. I assumed since you asked for sum you wanted `.sum()`, but perhaps `.mosaic()` is what you want. Or `.median()` if you want the median of all the images rather than the most reent available image.